# How do you parse a date and time string with offset using NodaTime?

Tags: nodatime

I am trying to learn how to use NodaTime within my application, but cannot find very many examples of how to do certain things with this library.

Given:

- date/time text of `"2012/08/30 17:45:00"`
- the format string is `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`
- the date/time offset from UTC is `-5`

How do I parse this with NodaTime to get an

- `OffsetDateTime`?
- `Instant`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using pure NodaTime code, there is not currently a direct parser for an `OffsetDateTime`. See the [documented limitations](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/userguide/limitations.html). However, you can construct one by parsing a `LocalDateTime` and an `Offset` separately:

```
var ldt = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                              .Parse("2012/08/30 17:45:00")
                              .Value;

var o = OffsetPattern.GeneralInvariantPattern
                     .Parse("-05")
                     .Value;

var odt = new OffsetDateTime(ldt, o);
```

There is a similar parser for `Instant`, but it requires a UTC time - not an offset.

You could also just use the text parsing for `DateTimeOffset` in the BCL, and then do:

```
var odt = OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(dto);
```

Either way, once you have an `OffsetDateTime`, it is convertible to an `Instant`:

```
var instant = odt.ToInstant();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  It was not clear to me, and I could not find examples, of how to use the LocalDateTimePattern for parsing.

Comment: Also realize that I just took `.Value` from the parse result.  You may want to check that the result was valid first.

Comment: In my case .GetValueOrThrow() is appropriate, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: One thing to note: version 1.2 is basically all about text. So it will definitely make it into that. Oh, and if the offset is always going to be -5, I'd just use `Offset.FromHours` instead of parsing it :)